# mbed-os compile - <new> library missing in arm-gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, mbed

I am getting the following error message when i have `mbed-os` and my own library installed side by side

folder layout:

```
.
|_mbed-os
|_library
```

`/mbed-os/platform/Callback.h:21:15: fatal error: new: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

which is originating form the following line:

`#include <new>`

Including from this file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
 * @file timer_platform.h
 */
#include "mbed.h"
#include "timer_interface.h"

/**
 * definition of the Timer struct. Platform specific
 */
struct Timer Timer;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The error occurs when i run `mbed compile`

I am running Windows 10 64bit with mbed-cli in version 1.0.0. The compiler is the gcc-arm-none-eabi 5.4

Where should this library be located? How can i track the error down? I am quite new to C++ but do have some experience with C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is because you're referencing the `mbed.h` header (or `Callback.h`) from a .c file. Rename to C++.

If you need the file to be C, then wrap in an `extern "C" {}` block.

Comment: I updated my question with the file i am including from, is it right how i did it?

Comment: Don't put the `include mbed.h` into the `extern "C" {` block. Put it outside.